# getComputedStyle('background-color') returns transparent, does not inherit ancestor's

Tags: javascript, css, background-color, getcomputedstyle

getComputedStyle is supposed to return the final computed CSS property value. But for background-color, all browsers return *transparent* (or rgba(x,x,x,0)) instead of computing in inherited value from ancestors.

The only time the method works is if the element has a background color specified **directly** (even if through its class, but not through parent's definifions). But that makes getComputedStyle useless, it should take in account all ancestor's definitions.

The method works fine for other things like color as shown in the fiddle.

How can i get the effective background color of an element in JS instead of every element telling me it is transparent?

```js
let para = document.querySelector('p');
let compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(para);
para.textContent = 'Incorrect background-color: ' + compStyles.getPropertyValue('background-color') + ', but font color is correct: ' + compStyles.getPropertyValue('color');
```

```css
/* no colors are specified for p */
p {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 2;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

/* this is the important part, only color gets inherited, not background-color */
div {
  background-color: purple;
  color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<!-- Original example taken from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle -->

<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

If it helps, the X question is How do i compute color luminosity difference between font color and background for each element in a page in an userscript ;)
That getComputedStyle does not work makes it not doable imho. But this question should be interesting on its own.

Comment: If you look in the DOM inspector, it also says the computed style is `rgba(0,0,0,0`.

Comment: the answer is simple : background is not inherited. Color is inherited

Comment: @barmar i don't see that in Firefox, only color shows on the p tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because **background-color** property is not inherited by the children elements (unlike the **color** property).

You can read more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance

Comment: Thanks, sadly that page does not list them all, just gives border as an example. Do you know of a complete list of non-inherited properties?

Comment: I don't know if there's a complete list, but you can check a property on MDN to see if it's inherited. For example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color (table above browser compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct result, because background color is not inherited. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color#Specifications):

> **Initial value** `transparent`
>   **Applies to**  all elements. It also applies to `::first-letter` and `::first-line`.
>   **Inherited**   no
>   **Media**   visual
>   **Computed value**  computed color
>   **Animation type**  a color
>   **Canonical order** the unique non-ambiguous order defined by the formal grammar

Answer (score 1):

To piggyback on other answers.  Here's a working example using inherited css.

```
/* no colors are specified for p */
p {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 2;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: inherit;  /* I added this */
}

/* this is the important part, only color gets inherited, not background-color */
div {
  background-color: purple;
  color: lightblue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/meq6x5ay/

Comment: Thanks, nice idea with the inherit, that could help me walk the node tree of a page without caring for (un)nesting. It is unfortunate that it is not the default, but i guess with all the positioning a single bgcolor would not even be always decidable.